# Using namespaces with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

Hi I am trying to pass a string into a namespace but have no idea of how to do this, there is a single ajax request that returns a string that I want to pass into the Clubs array

Can anyone explain in this example how I pass the var clubs into the clubs array below it?

```
$(function () { Website.init(); } );

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'home/ajax_get_online_properties',
        data: { },
        success : function(data){
         console.log(data);
         var clubs = data;             
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });

var Website = {
    clubs: [
        'Club 1',
        'Club 2',
        'Club 3'
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this :-

json returned from data via ajax request - 
    ["Club A1","Club B2","Club C3"] 

and trying to get the Website.clubs to display as such

    Website.clubs : [ "Club A1","Club B2","Club C3" ]

Any ideas

Comment: So it's fine. You just have to decode the JSON and access `Website.clubs` at the right time, i.e. in the Ajax callback (or whenever you are sure that the Ajax call succeeded).

Comment: Thanks felix i will give this another bash shortly :) really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Felix answer above - seems the best method